# не работает, как исправить? Данный код?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

js

не получается заполнить массив, что нужно исправить?

```
   send(data){
      for(let i = 0; this.allCartProduct.length; i++){
        if(this.allCartProduct[i] == data){
          this.allCartProduct[i] = data
        }else{
          this.allCartProduct.push(data)
        } 
      }
    }
```

код полностью

```
<script>
import CartList from '../src/components/cartList'
export default {
  data(){
    return{
      hidden: false,
        name: '',
        sub_name: '',
        address: '',
        allCartProduct: [],
        arrCart: [],
    }
  },
  components: { 
    CartList 
  },
  props:['storage'],
  methods:{
  send_req(){
      alert(JSON.stringify({name: this.name,sub_name: this.sub_name,address: this.address,cart: this.allCartProduct}))
    },
  send(data){
      for(let i = 0; this.allCartProduct.length; i++){
        if(this.allCartProduct[i] == data){
          this.allCartProduct[i] = data
        }else{
          this.allCartProduct.push(data)
        } 
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: он каждый раз в else попадает, вот и все, нужно поставить другое условие

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
import CartList from '../src/components/cartList'
export default {
  data(){
    return{
      hidden: false,
        name: '',
        sub_name: '',
        address: '',
        allCartProduct: [],
        arrCart: [],
    }
  },
  components: { 
    CartList 
  },
  props:['storage'],
  methods:{
  send_req(){
      alert(JSON.stringify({name: this.name,sub_name: this.sub_name,address: this.address,cart: this.allCartProduct}))
    },
  send(data){
      for(let i = 0; i < this.allCartProduct.length; i++){
        if(JSON.stringify(this.allCartProduct[i]) == JSON.stringify(data)){
          this.allCartProduct[i] = data
        }else{
          this.allCartProduct.push(data)
        } 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: JSON.stringify не очень хорошо использовать для глубокого сравнения, некоторые поля могут не сериализовываться, что приведет к ошибочному результату.

Comment: @Grundy конечно. Но думаю автор понимает что просто сравнить указатели это мало.

Comment: В текущем цикле, это не самая большая проблема :)

Comment: Даже не обратил внимания :)))